# I am trying to send a msg to everyone that has set there channel, but I have problem sending msgs

Tags: discord.py

In theory, the code should have sent a msg to all the servers that have set there channel! Altho it seems not to be working. I think its because I can't get the channel_id even tho I have done it in sqlite. Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The client is online!")
    db = sqlite3.connect('entry.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main(
    guild_id TEXT,
    channel_id,
    user_id
    )
    ''')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title = "Pong!",
    description = f"Your ping is {client.latency}ms !", color=0xf9c900)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def public(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel, winners: int, time: int, link:str, *, prize:str):
    db = sqlite3.connect('entry.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    channel_id = cursor.execute(f"SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        return
    else:
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for channel in channel_id:
                try:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = f"**Giving Away {prize}**",
                    description = f"React with  to enter! \n **{winners}** winner \n \n  Must be in **{link}** to enter!", color=0xf9c900)
                    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    asyncio.sleep(1)
                    await msg.add_reaction('')
                    asyncio.sleep(time)
                except Exception:
                    continue
                else:
                    break

@client.command()
async def setchannel(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
        db = sqlite3.connect('entry.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO main(guild_id, channel_id) VALUES(?,?)")
            val = (ctx.guild.id, channel.id)
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f":white_check_mark: succesfully added the giveaway channel {channel.mention}!",color=0x00ced1)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        elif result is not None:
            sql = ("UPDATE main SET channel_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
            val = (channel.id, ctx.guild.id)
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f":white_check_mark: succesfully updated the giveaway channel {channel.mention}!",color=0x00ced1)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

The part I am trying to figure out is this part:

```
@client.command()
async def public(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel, winners: int, time: int, link:str, *, prize:str):
    db = sqlite3.connect('entry.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    channel_id = cursor.execute(f"SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        return
    else:
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for channel in channel_id:
                try:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = f"**Giving Away {prize}**",
                    description = f"React with  to enter! \n **{winners}** winner \n \n  Must be in **{link}** to enter!", color=0xf9c900)
                    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    asyncio.sleep(1)
                    await msg.add_reaction('')
                    asyncio.sleep(time)
                except Exception:
                    continue
                else:
                    break
```

This part is suppose to send a message to the ones that have set there channel! But it isn't working and its not sending me any errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your SQL `"SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}"` is going to retrieve the `channel_id` for the guild that you ran the `public` command in.

Then, you get one row of data using `cursor.fetchone()`, but in your loop you are attempting to loop over `channel_id`, which is not the data you want, so I doubt your for loop is even running.

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: You need to create a SQL statement that SELECTs all the rows in the table WHERE channel_id is not Null or whatever depending on your schema.  Then you will use [fetchall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) to get all rows and iterate over them.  Also just fyi, you need to use [aiosqlite](https://pypi.org/project/aiosqlite/) in async python, as the sync sqlite lib could cause some weird behavior by blocking the event loop.